# Как через jquery добавить класс к элементу внутри которого есть элемент с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как через jquery к div с классом wrap добавить класс например: cls_add при условии, что внутри div скласcом wrap есть элементы с классом: cls_in

Пример есть код:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='cls_in'></div>
</div>
```

Чтобы было так если cls_in есть:

```
<div class='wrap cls_add'>
    <div class='cls_in'></div>
</div>
```

так если нет cls_in:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='other'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.wrap .cls_in').closest('.wrap').toggleClass('cls_add');
```

---

```
$('.wrap .cls_in').closest('.wrap').addClass('cls_add');
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.wrap').has('.cls_in').addClass('cls_add');
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ